# Mostrar enlace clickable en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enlaces-ancla

Tengo la siguiente parte de código dond muestra el título que tengo guardado en una base de datos. Lo que me gustaria hacer es que en ese mismo título se pueda hacer un enlace clickable que muestre a donde va dirigido y puedas hacer click. El enlace está guardado en la misma tabla como Documento. Sería posible? Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
        fila = new TableRow();



        celda = new TableCell();
        celda.Text = lista[i].Titulo;
        fila.Cells.Add(celda);
```

Comment: Has probado creando un `HyperLink` y agregandolo a los controles de `celda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un `HyperLink`, y añadirlo a la celda de la siguiente forma:

```
HyperLink hl= new HyperLink();
hl.Text = "TEXTO";
hl.NavigateUrl = "URL";

TableCell celda = new TableCell();
celda.Controls.Add(hl);
```